# Is it possible to retain IP address when stopping/starting an AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Reading [Amazon's documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html) it appears that the default behavior for an EC2 instance to to release the current IP address and reassign a new one at some point in the processes depending on whether you are using Classic or VPC:

> EC2-Classic: We release the public and private IPv4 addresses for the
>   instance when you stop the instance, and assign new ones when you
>   restart it.
>
> EC2-VPC: The instance retains its private IPv4 addresses and any IPv6
>   addresses when stopped and restarted. We release the public IPv4
>   address and assign a new one when you restart it.

In my environment it would be nice if I could find a way to retain the IP address.  Does anyone know of a way to do this with EC2 instances?

Comment: Specifically provision an elastic IP and attach it to the instance.

Answer (score 15):

Assign an [Elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) to your instance. That IP is yours until you release it. Stop, start, terminate, reassign to a different instance, you can do whatever you like.

Elastic IPs are free, but cost a small amount if they're not attached to a running instance.

There's no way to retain the automatically assigned public IP through a stop / start cycle.

Comment: Here's [the Elastic IP pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/#Elastic_IP_Addresses). If you're trying to save up on hourly usage by shutting down the instance once in a while, but use the Elastic IP, it may not get much cheaper after all

Answer (score 4):

You seem to quote the wrong part of AWS documentation. Take a look here (from your same link):

- EC2-Classic: We disassociate any Elastic IP address that's associated with the instance. You're charged for Elastic IP addresses that aren't associated with an instance. When you restart the instance, you must associate the Elastic IP address with the instance; we don't do this automatically.
- EC2-VPC: The instance retains its associated Elastic IP addresses. You're charged for any Elastic IP addresses associated with a stopped instance.

So, it seems that using an **EC2-VPC instance with an Elastic IP address** you can stop/reboot the instance *and retain the assigned public IP address*

Comment: My reading of the question suggests Abe wasn't using Elastic IP addresses. They were using the default assigned public IP.

Comment: Maybe, but without an Elastic IP it should not be possible to obtain what the OP asked

Comment: I know, that's why I suggested that in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

As the 1st step you need to allocate IP from Amazon (in other words you need to ask Amazon to give you persistent IP):

> To allocate an Elastic IP address
>
> Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
>
> In the navigation pane, choose Network & Security, Elastic IPs.
>
> Choose Allocate Elastic IP address.
>
> For Public IPv4 address pool, choose one of the following:
>
> Amazon's pool of IPv4 addresses—If you want an IPv4 address to be
> allocated from Amazon's pool of IPv4 addresses.
>
> My pool of public IPv4 addresses—If you want to allocate an IPv4
> address from an IP address pool that you have brought to your AWS
> account. This option is disabled if you do not have any IP address
> pools.
>
> Customer owned pool of IPv4 addresses—If you want to allocate an IPv4
> address from a pool created from your on-premises network for use with
> an AWS Outpost. This option is disabled if you do not have an AWS
> Outpost.
>
> (Optional) Add or remove a tag.
>
> [Add a tag] Choose Add new tag and do the following:
>
> For Key, enter the key name.
>
> For Value, enter the key value.
>
> [Remove a tag] Choose Remove to the right of the tag’s Key and Value.
>
> Choose Allocate.

As the 2nd step you need to select allocated IP and associate it with your instance:

> To associate an Elastic IP address with an instance
>
> Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
>
> In the navigation pane, choose Elastic IPs.
>
> Select the Elastic IP address to associate and choose Actions,
> Associate Elastic IP address.
>
> For Resource type, choose Instance.
>
> For instance, choose the instance with which to associate the Elastic
> IP address. You can also enter text to search for a specific instance.
>
> (Optional) For Private IP address, specify a private IP address with
> which to associate the Elastic IP address.
>
> Choose Associate.
>
> To associate an Elastic IP address with a network interface
>
> Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
>
> In the navigation pane, choose Elastic IPs.
>
> Select the Elastic IP address to associate and choose Actions,
> Associate Elastic IP address.
>
> For Resource type, choose Network interface.
>
> For Network interface, choose the network interface with which to
> associate the Elastic IP address. You can also enter text to search
> for a specific network interface.
>
> (Optional) For Private IP address, specify a private IP address with
> which to associate the Elastic IP address.
>
> Choose Associate.

[Here is the full instruction.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#working-with-eips)